# How to get the value of status?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have this ajax request :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: sUrl,
        data: sQueryStr,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {   
        }
    });
```

when i inspect firebug, i am getting data as

```
"{"status":"N"}"
```

my server side return is :-

```
$verification['status']='N';
print_r(json_encode($verification));
```

but the problem is how can i get the value of status which is N in success method ?

Comment: did you tried data.status or data.d.status in the success method

Answer (score 0):

It's an object. access it as `data.success`. Also set `dataType` to `json`.

```
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {   
       alert(data.success);

       // To examine the structure of `data`
       console.dir(data);
    }
```

Comment: @Sparkx are you sure the success function is firing? In other words, is your Ajax call actually succeeding?

Comment: @Sparkx You also set the dataType to json? What you have printed in Firebug is a string representation of JSON. It hasn't been evaluated as JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: sUrl,
        data: sQueryStr,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
           alert(data.status);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Some little modifications:

`success: function(data) {}` => `success: function(data) {console.log(data.status)}`

`print_r(json_encode($verification));` => `echo json_encode($verification);`

Comment: @Sparkx Then `console.log(data)`, and check if `data` is a valid json.

Comment: how can i chk that using `eval` function

Comment: @Sparkx Sorry, for security and other concerns, `eval()` is never an option. And by "check if `data` is a valid json", I mean check it manually, use some json validators.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
alert(data.status);
```

if your data is like this

{'key1':'val2','key2':'val2'}

then you can get data like

```
data.key1;
data.key2;
```